# Saving image to Firebase Storage using Google Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

For a couple months I have been newbie-ing my way through trying to use busboy to store images in Firebase Storage handled by Google Cloud Functions triggered by sendgrid inbound email webhooks.

I am lost and finding my way through trial and error.

Current stage: I have the file data in a buffer form, with the logs showing things like "<Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 48 00 48 0"

When saved to Firebase Storage, the correct size and name are there, but no image is rendered and an access token was failed to be created.

Do I need to save the ArrayBuffer as a blob before saving to Firebase Storage?

**Google Cloud Functions**

```
 const functions = require("firebase-functions");
 const admin = require("firebase-admin");
 const Busboy = require("busboy");
 admin.initializeApp();

 exports.parseInbound = 
   functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

  let attachment = { file: null };
  let fileData = null;

 try {
    const busboy = Busboy({headers: req.headers});

    busboy.on("file", async (fieldname, file, 
    filename, encoding, mimetype) => {

     file.on("data", function (data) {
       fileData = Buffer.toString(data);
      }
    });
  
    attachment = {
      fieldname: fieldname,
      file: file,
      filename: filename,
      encoding: encoding,
      mimetype: mimetype,
  
     };
   }
 });

busboy.on("finish", async function () {
  
  if (attachment) {
      attachment.file = fileData;
       await uploadImgToStorage(attachment);
     }

});

//req.pipe(busboy); <--this terminates the function 
   immediately
busboy.end(req.rawBody); 
res.status(200).send("Email processed successfully");

 } catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
   res.status(500).send("Error processing email");
  }
});

async function uploadImgToStorage(attachment) {
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
  try {
    // Uploads a local file to the bucket
    
      await bucket
         .file(attachment.filename)
         .save(attachment.file, { contentType: 
             attachment.filename.mimetype })
  
  .catch((e) => {
 
    console.log(e);
  });
 );
 } catch (e) {
   throw new Error(e);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it ever happen to you that right after you take the time to post a question to SO, that you come up with the answer directly after?

Simple answer is that I needed to convert the buffer into base64, so I added the second line of code below:

```
      fileData = Buffer.toString(data);
      fileData = fileData.toString("base64");
```